# how to set backgroundImage of DIV using angular response.data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I used to set the background image of a div with a get request like so:

```
style="background-image:url('/api/image')"
```

Now I want to do an $http request in Angular, get the image from response.data, and then set it like so:

```
document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = response.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers should have no knowledge of your DOM. You should be attaching the data to your $scope and then applying it in your view.

```
$scope.imagePath = response.data;
```

and in your view.

```
<span id="img" style="background-image:url('{{imagePath}}')"></span>
```